# Set gradient on stroke android

Tags: java, android, gradient, shapes

I have a circular drawable on which I set a 8dp white stroke, like this:

```
    circleImage = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    circleImage.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
    drawable = (GradientDrawable) circleImage.getBackground();
    drawable.setStroke(8, getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
```

The XML for `circleImage` looks like this:

```
 <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
            android:clickable="true"/>
```

What I want to do now is to change the `drawable.setStroke` to include a gradient color like this

[image: 1]

I suppose the easiest way to achieve this is to write something in the drawable XML, but I don't quite know how to achieve this.

roundcorner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle" >
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
            android:topRightRadius="100dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
            />
        <padding
            android:left="2dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:bottom="2dp"
            />
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="100dp"
            />
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should do something like this. Use `layer-list` with 2 shapes. First one is for gradient stroke and second one is for solid.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="360"
                android:startColor="#543456"
                android:endColor="#ff00b5"
                android:type="linear" />
            <size android:width="24dp"
                  android:height="24dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

This code looks like this
[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you need inner color to be transparent, then you can use a ring shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="2dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/sea_green"
        android:endColor="@color/black"
        android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

[image]

Comment: How to make the same effect with rectangle?

Comment: @I.Step, maybe try to use `android:shape="rectangle"`?

Comment: Yes but with rectangle you do not get a border you get a rectangle, and if you try to make a border with two rectangles where one has little padding to the other. It wont work with inner rectangle transparent background.